# Send GPS position from Android App to external Navigation Map and navigate there by voice

Tags: android

Does anyone know if there is a possibility to send from Android App GPS position to external navigation system in order to navigate to this position?

*Example:*

*I have an application with gas stations in my country. In application I have GPS positions of gas stations stored. By clicking some button I want to go to some navigation map app and I want for user to be navigated by voice and map to this gas stasion.*

I know about Google Maps navigation, but it is in beta and works in US, if I know correctly.

Do you know any Navigation Maps that support external input of position to navigate to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will call Google Navigation (Beta):

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
 Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=40.7143528,-74.0059731"));
 startActivity(intent);
```

Just pass in your stored Lat/Long values as variables.

Good Luck!